# WooCommerce send items to PayPal in a wrong way

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I have a little problem in woocommerce + paypal
does anyone know why when i'm switching from checkout page to paypal website for ending my order instead of showing me each item per row,
it shows the items all together like in the image ( the standard one is on the right and mine is on the left )
and, most of all, why i have shipping and handling in the items instead of having it after total?

[image: Screenshots]

Comment: Is this default PayPal? Or a PayPal plugin?

Comment: @helgatheviking default paypal

Comment: Do you have markup in your product titles?

Comment: @helgatheviking yes i have, but in my wordpress website hey are hidden.
this is another problem but I can solve it later :D

Comment: Of course they are hidden, on your website they are processed as HTML. When sent to PayPal they are showing as text. I would consider reworking your titles to not use HTML markup.

Comment: mmh...i'll try to solve it, but i think is not the point, i mean why if i order 4 product it shows that i'm buying one?
And why standard shipping is treated like an item?
maybe a plugin can solve this, what do you think about it @helgatheviking?
smth like https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue with the html in the titles: http://tinyurl.com/ok93tgs PayPal can't parse the HTML. Depending on the markup, it is possible that you are completely messing up the PayPal markup. I would definitely remove the markup before proceeding. If your items do not require shipping (such as virtual items) then a shipping cost will not be displayed.

Comment: Thank you is better without markup, but doesn't solve the problem, infact, as you see from the image, in my cart i have 2 products(the blue one and the pink one) but they act like just one...how I can split them like the image on the right?? like 
product one --> price
product two --> price etc.

Comment: Do you have a link? I actually *can't* tell what I am looking at from your image because my Italian is crap. :) And I've never seen this problem occur before. I would suggest disabling all plugins except WooCommerce and possibly even switching to a default theme to try to isolate the problem.

Comment: @helgatheviking I could show to you the entire site but how can i give you link in pvt?

Comment: Don't know how to set up a private chat. You are sure that this problem still persists... testing from the beginning now that the markup problem is resolved?

Comment: @helgatheviking yes, i start from zero installed wp+woocommerce in local and the problem is still there...btw thank you for your help, really you where so kind :)

Comment: @ flow_, did you ever resolve this? I have the same problem - most of my item costs are being collected together and shown to the user at Paypal checkout as just two items, one correct and one supposedly costing the total of all the others.

Answer (score -2):

I've the same issue...and i've solved: try to set "off" tax setting

Ciao! 
Avevo lo stesso problema....devi delezionare l'opzione calcola le imposte!

Federico